# Multiple & (and) condition not working properly for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, data-science

I have two data sets - structured_data (having 4000 + records) and record_data (have 400 records). I am trying to compare what all records are present in record_data that matches with structured_data.

I do this by using some common attributes from both the dataset by using the following condition -

filter_df = record_data[record_data.UnitNumber.isin(structured_data.UnitNumber) & record_data.price.isin(structured_data.price) & record_data.zipcode.astype(int).isin(structured_data.zipcode.astype(int))  & record_data.bedrooms.isin(structured_data.bedrooms) & record_data.bathrooms.isin(structured_data.bathrooms)]

This condition is not giving only those records that holds true for each of the above condition. While many records in the result do follow the condition but not all. I made sure that datatypes of the attributes taken above are the same in both the datasets.

What I am trying to achieve is integrate both the datasets and eventually have one dataset giving all the unique records.

Wondering if there is anything wrong with the code. Will be happy to share the dataset if required. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this example illustrate your issue? More precisely, is the last output what you would expect?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: record_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'a'],[2,6,'b'],[2,2,'c']], columns=['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'something_else'])

In [3]: record_data
Out[3]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              a
1         2          6              b
2         2          2              c

In [4]: structured_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'d'],[2,3,'e'],[1,3,'e']], columns=['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'something_else'])

In [5]: structured_data
Out[5]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              d
1         2          3              e
2         1          3              e

In [6]: record_data[record_data.bedrooms.isin(structured_data.bedrooms) & record_data.bathrooms.isin(structured_data.bathrooms)]
Out[6]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              a
2         2          2              c
```

---

*edit:*

Based on your answers below, the issue is that you check each column independently. You get the record `{'bedrooms': 2, 'bathrooms': 6}` because `structured_data` contains a row with `bedrooms=2` and also contains a row with `bathrooms=6`. Your condition does not require that it's the same row.

Let's take a bigger example.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: structured_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'d'],[2,3,'e'],[1,3,'e'],[1,6,'e']], columns=['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'something_else'])

In [4]: structured_data
Out[4]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              d
1         2          3              e
2         1          3              e
3         1          6              e

In [5]: record_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'a'],[2,6,'b'],[2,2,'c'],[1,8,'g'],[4,2,'h']], columns=['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'something_else'])

In [6]: record_data
Out[6]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              a
1         2          6              b
2         2          2              c
3         1          8              g
4         4          2              h
```

Now let's decompose `record_data[record_data.bathrooms.isin(structured_data.bathrooms) & record_data.bedrooms.isin(structured_data.bedrooms)]` and see what happens step by step.

```
In [7]: record_data.bathrooms.isin(structured_data.bathrooms)
Out[7]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: bathrooms, dtype: bool
```

Notice that the indices are those of `record_data`. The output doesn't say anything about which rows of `structured_data` were matched.

```
In [8]: record_data.bedrooms.isin(structured_data.bedrooms)
Out[8]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: bedrooms, dtype: bool
```

Again, we have no information about `structured_data` rows.

```
In [9]: record_data.bathrooms.isin(structured_data.bathrooms) & record_data.bedrooms.isin(structured_data.bedrooms)
Out[9]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

In [10]: record_data[record_data.bathrooms.isin(structured_data.bathrooms) & record_data.bedrooms.isin(structured_data.bedrooms)]
Out[10]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              a
1         2          6              b
2         2          2              c
```

> Wondering if there is anything wrong with the code.

Do you understand what's wrong now?

---

> What I am trying to achieve is integrate both the datasets and eventually have one dataset giving all the unique records.

Just to clarify, you want all records that appear in either dataset? Or only records that are in both datasets?

Assuming the former.

A few ideas:

1. Given that both data sets are small, you could use Python `sets` and compute the union.

   ```
   In [28]: { tuple(rec) for rec in record_data[['bedrooms', 'bathrooms']].values.tolist() }
   Out[28]: {(1, 2), (1, 8), (2, 2), (2, 6), (4, 2)}
   ```
2. You can concatenate your datasets (assuming they have the same columns) and use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to get unique combinations. The doc on [Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) has plenty of examples.

---

*edit 2:*

Based on your new answer, you can use `merge()` to do the equivalent of a SQL [inner join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [12]: pd.merge(left=record_data, right=structured_data.drop('something_else', axis=1), how='inner', on=['bedrooms', 'bathrooms'])
Out[12]: 
   bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              a
```

Comment: Yes, the last output is what I am expecting

Comment: The above code wont work if I add (1,6,'e) in strucutured_data. Basically its checking the condition individually. What I am looking for is to if bedrooms matches, then match bathrooms of the same record and not look in the whole dataframe. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks Laurie for taking the time out and clarifying my question here. I understood that the condition is not checking if all the attributes match for the same record, rather it is considering what all condition holds true for each of them individually. What I was trying to achieve was match 400 records with the dataset having 4000 records, and if they match (based on the condition/attributes above) then they are considered to be one record, if they dont match then it is a separate record.

Comment: I still will try to find a workaround for making this approach work where I can just match certain common attributes from both the data sets before I eventually move on to explore Merge, join, and concatenate. Once again, Thank you!

Comment: @ShobhitTalwar Using the second example above, what output do you want?

Comment: The output I want is as below -
bedrooms  bathrooms something_else
0         1          2              a

This is because there is only one combination of bedrooms and bathrooms in record_data which matches with the similar bedrooms and bathrooms combinations in structured_data. Get it?